Unable to install Jenkins Plugins java.io.IOException: Tunnel failed, got: 403
Trying to configure Jenkins for some personal tryouts on a company laptop. First the Jenkins instance started as an offline instance. On proceeding further I found that no plugings are available and it is unable to connect https://updates.jenkins.io/update-center.json (403 indicated auth failed).
But I can open the same json in the same browser with the same network
https://i.sstatic.net/517LLeqH.png
I had gone through a lot of articles here and tried the following but did not succeed

Started jenkins with the follwoing command "java -jar jenkins.war --enable-future-java flag"
But it showed the following error with jenkins instance

https://i.sstatic.net/zOUHe7K5.png

Tried changing the plugin url from https to http but issue to connect URL persists

https://i.sstatic.net/Hlb3tm3O.png

Tried configuring the proxy setting but it cannot access http://www.google.com

https://i.sstatic.net/it64Squj.png

Tried to install through cli but since it cannot access the json it throws junk value

https://i.sstatic.net/53Yo8ZtH.png
Can you please advise if there is any workaround to get the plugins???
